# AWS CRON expression to run 2 mins past every 5 mins

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I currently have a cloud watch event that triggers a Lambda every 5 mins 00,05,10,15,20...
schedule_expression = "cron(0/5 * * * ? *)"
However, I would like to trigger the jobs at same 5 minutes interval but at 02,07,12,17. Is there a way to achieve that in AWS CRON schedule?

Answer (score 2):

Is there anything stopping you from just inputting the numbers directly?

`cron(2,7,12,17,22,27,32,37,42,47,52,57 * * ? *)`

That should be a valid expression, no need for fancy arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer
schedule_expression = "cron(2/5 * * * ? *)"